# Azure Tables ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync with Skip

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

In an older version (5.0.2) of the Azure Storage SDK, I had the following code to retrieve items in a storage table, which could do skip & take:

```
var tableEntries = table.ExecuteQuery(new TableQuery())
    .Skip(skipCount)
    .Take(maximumResultCount)
    .ToArray();
```

I am rewriting code to be async and have upgraded to the latest storage package (8.5) and it appears the intention is to use `ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync`. I've figured out from the doco it's possible to do a `Take` thusly:

```
var tableEntries = table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(new TableQuery().Take(maximumResultCount));
```

However I cannot see how to do a skip.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Can you please tell which older version you're referring to?

Comment: @GauravMantri Sure, previous version was 5.0.2.0

Comment: `table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync` returns a task. If you get the result of this task, you should be able to use Skip on that.

Comment: I'd suggest you to read something about async/await, e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async